# WP REST API - Get category name instead of id on post request

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-api

is there any solution to get the category name instead of id in the response on following endpoint? `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/:post_id`

Thanks Guys

Comment: Add `?_embed` to the end and the categories are populated in the response under `wp:term:[id]`

Comment: with `?_embed` tags array returns empty. categories are populating correctly, WP version = 5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By adding the `_embed` query parameter to the endpoint, you can also retrieve categories.
It will be populated under `_embeded` object and then you can access it under `wp:term` in the JSON response.
Here's an example of how to do it for `posts`:

```
{{site}}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed=
```

Notice that `_embed` can get different values. For example, if you only need to embed `wp:term` (includes categories and tags) in the final result you can do this:

```
{{site}}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed=wp:term
```

Answer (score -3):

WP REST API doesn't provide category name in `'/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/:post_id'` you can call another API request to get category name: `/wp/v2/categories/<id>`

For more details visit [WP REST API](https://v2.wp-api.org/reference/categories/)